# What should I be aware of when applying identical SQLAlchemy migrations (models made after the fact) on a pre-exisitng Postgres database?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, database-migration

I have a specific question around generation and application of migrations to a pre-existing postgres database, the models have been created in SQLAlchemy (after the original DDLs), and I intend to use Alembic (wrapped by Flask-Migrate) to migrate our application away from the currently defined DDLs, which were run against the database a long time ago. We are moving towards a more defined migration process where schema upgrades can be handled in a sane way.

My question is what should I be aware of when doing this? I am aware of Automap, but I'd much prefer to just add the ORM and standardise our schema creation.

My concern at the moment is that because the tables weren't created by the ORM/migration process, then I will have problems moving it across, basically, I'm aware that I'm unaware of how some things work under the hood. Feel free to tell me if I'm concerned about a null threat.

Cheers.